# 502 Bad Gateway https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Is anyone else getting a 502 Bad Gateway error when trying to access:
https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v2/rest?userIp=121.74.173.27

API Explorer also seems to be down?
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Or is there something else I should be doing?

Thank you!

Comment: We're seeing the same issue as well. It started at ~6:30PM PST.

Comment: There was an outage which was over before I got a chance to post about it, sorry. Things appear back to normal. Sorry for everyone affected, the issue was beyond the scope of the Drive API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to have started working again after being down for ~ 1 hr.
Nothing needed to be done.

Would be nice if there was a status page for the Google APIs as well.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

We're seeing frequent 502 Bad Gateway errors too. The HTML response from Google recommends retrying in 30 seconds.

The Google Drive API documentation recommends implementing an exponential back off to deal with transient errors.
[https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors](http://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors)